# React Navigation pass navigation prop

Tags: react-native-navigation

According to the react navigation docs the navigation prop gets passed when you select a screen from the stack navigator.

In example if I have two routes registered:
HomeScreen
Details

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}>
        <Text>Press me</Text>
      </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Simple enough! However let us suppose I had another component being called:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <MyOtherComponent />
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

and I would like this:

```
<Button
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}>
            <Text>Press me</Text>
          </Button>
```

to be in , how would I do this?
Would I pass the prop from HomeScreen to MyOtherComponent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer in the docs.  For anyone else this might help that didn't go through all the docs like me.

I can use `withNavigation`

In the example of MyOtherComponent I can do the following:

import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

```
class MyOtherComponent extends React.Component {
render stuff here
}
```

export default withNavigation(MyBackButton);